# Can't set icon image of JButton

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, openoffice.org

I am using `JButton` in an Open Office Plugin's interface. I want to show image on button instead of text. When I do following, the button itself disappears!

```
btnPath = new javax.swing.JButton("Select File..");
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Path\\toFile\\add.png");
btnPath.setIcon(img);
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) `new ImageIcon("C:\\Path\\toFile\\add.png");` For starters, use `ImageIO` to load the image.  It gives a lot better feed-back. 2) By the time of deployment, those (image) resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`. 3) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: *"..the button itself disappears!"* Smells like `setBounds(..)`..

Comment: Following give incompatible type error:

`ImageIcon img = ImageIO.read(MyClass.class.getResource("/resources/icon.gif"));`

Comment: `<head-desk>` it should be `ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(MyClass.class.getResource("/resources/icon.gif")));` but it will need a `try`/`catch` as well.